# Filling an array with command line parameters

Tags: c, arrays, command, line

I need to fill an array[2][8] with some words passed as command line parameters (words should be separated with whitespace). I don't know how to connect CLP with my array. What if I have more than 17 letters?

I wrote code just for counting and printing parameters.

```
#define ROWS 2
#define COLUMNS 8
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int counter;
  if(argc > 17)
  {
     printf("Too many elements!");
     return 0;
  }
  printf("Command line includes %d parameters:\n", argc - 1);
  for(counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
  printf("%d: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT : I have to use pointers. Array [2][8] must be filled with words after which we put whitespace. I think that 2x8 array is storing exactly 16 characters, including whitespaces. I don't know how to show when you exceed 16 letters limit.

Comment: _I need to fill an array[2][8]_ does not make sense in light of your other questions.  i.e. that array will hold only two, very short strings.  Later you ask about a string of size greater than 17.  By the way, your code, as is, will work to print any number of parameters, each with any length.

Comment: Is it a real requirement to limit the command line parameters to 17?

Comment: Because array is 2x8 it can store no more than16 characters

Comment: But an array with 2 rows of 8 columns each would be limited to holding only 8 `char` per section.  As written, your example does not reference the `#defines`  of `ROWS` and `COLUMNS`.  Were these included with the intent of creating an array?

Comment: I see your edit, but it still does not provide an example of a set of command line parameters you are expected to capture, or how you are expected to store them.  Can you please show the rows and columns of parameters as you are required to store them.?

Comment: echo.c c lanugage is ok and I want to store and printf c lanugage is ok.

Comment: So the columns might be titled _file_ and _description_.  If that is the case, the command line arguments _c language_ should be surrounded with double quotes: `"c language"`.  This would be seen as a single command line argument. But it will not fit into a 2x8 matrix.  (See the edit to my answer in a few minutes to see an example of double quoted string with white space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What if I have more than 17 letters?*

`argc` is an abbreviation of *argument count*, so the statement: `if(argc > 17)` is in effect testing the number of command line arguments, not the count of characters in each one.

Additionally, the argument `char *argv[]` ( where `argv` is short for *argument vector* ) is typed to accommodate any number of `char` for each command line argument.

*Filling an array with command line parameters*
If you wanted to capture the contents of your command line arguments into an array, either a dynamically allocated set of buffers, or preferably a *[variable length array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/)* (available from `C99` on) are suitable for the task.  The dimensions of the array (of either type) can be obtained using `argc` (the number of arguments) and `strlen` of `argv[i]` in a loop to get the longest length of all of the arguments.  An example of this technique addresses your title question below.

Example of using a *[VLA](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/)*:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int counter;
  int len, maxLen=0;

  // find the longest length parameter
  for(counter = 0; counter < argc; counter++)
  {
      len = strlen(argv[counter]);
      if(len > maxLen) maxLen = len;
  }

  //using a variable length array, create a container for all parameters
  char array[argc][maxLen + 1];// +1 to allow room for null terminator

  // transfer contents of argv to VLA array
  for(counter = 0; counter < argc; counter++)   
  {
      strcpy(array[counter], argv[counter]);//copy CLPs into array
  }

  printf("Command line includes %d parameters:\n", argc - 1);
  for(counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
  printf("%d: %s\n", counter, array[counter]);
  return 0;
}
```

Example output for the arguments" *this that and the other thing andareallylongargumenttoshowthatargvcanaccomodate*.
[image]

Example output Using arguments with white space:
"this that" and the "other thing" andareallylongargumenttoshowthatargvcanaccomodate
[image]

***EDIT*** to address clarifications in comments.

The following test for (and limits) max number of arguments to `ROWS` , and allows length limits of arguments to exceed `COLUMNS-1`, but trims to length if too long.  If string is less than `COLUMNS-1` long, pads remaining space with `&`.  If string contains any white space, replaces it with `&`...

```
#define ROWS 2
#define COLUMNS 8
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int counter, i;

  char array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

  if(argc > 3) 
  {
      printf("Too many arguments.  2 max.\n(Hit any character to exit.)");
      getchar();
      return 0;
  }


  for(counter = 0; counter < argc-1; counter++) 
  {   //trim to legal string length.
      strncpy(array[counter], argv[counter+1], COLUMNS-1);
      array[counter][COLUMNS-1]=0;//set last char to null
      for(i=0;i<COLUMNS-1;i++)
      {   //test for any white space or NULL 
          //character within legal string length
          if((isspace(array[counter][i])) || array[counter][i] == NULL) array[counter][i] = '&';
      }
  }

  printf("Command line includes %d parameters:\n", argc - 1);
  for(counter = 0; counter < argc-1; counter++)
  printf("%d: %s\n", counter, array[counter]);
  return 0;
}
```

Results for example parameters - *echo.c "c language is ok"*:
[image]

Comment: But still I can fill array with as many words and letters as I want to.

Comment: I wanted to fill 1 gap in array with 1 letter

Comment: @Michael - can you please edit your question above with an example of what you want your output to look like.  I will try to address the question once I can see that edit, and understand what you need.

Comment: Basically my task is to create array[2][8] and fill it with words

Comment: @Micheal - with that array you can only hold two words (strings) each containing  a maximum of 7 visible characters and 1 `NULL` character.  For example _"string1"_ and _"string2"_ are 2 strings, each with 7 visible characters.  Does this represent what you need to capture?

Comment: Yeah, but this code is printing everything, no matter how many letters I input

Comment: @Michael - So do you want to test the input to limit it to a maximum string length of 7 (8 with `nul` terminator)?

Comment: I think I made it too difficult. Question I got says "create an array [2][8] and fill it with words typed as CLP. Replace all whitespaces with <&>"

Comment: You realize with those stipulations the longest command line parameter would be a string with maximum of 7 visible parameters? for example: _"string1"_.  And just to confirm I understand, with a shorter command line param, for example _"this"_ would use `&` to fill the rest of the space:  _"this&&&"_.  Is this what you need to do???

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to express.

Comment: @Michael -   In one of your comments above you provided `echo.c c lanugage` as an example of what you might see in your command line parameters.  The word _language_ is too long to fit into a 2x8 array.  Will you need to handle parameters longer than 7 characters?  That is, the word _language_ would have to be stored as: `|l|a|n|g|u|a|g|\0|`.  So it will print out as `languag`.  Is that okay?  If so, I will edit my post and illustrate how you can limit input, and fill white space with `&`.

Comment: That's all I needed. I'm very grateful you wanted to spend time on helping me.

Comment: @Michael - glad to help!